# Shorthand for a multivolume collection in authoryear-comp

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use `shorthand` with a `@mvcollection` in the `authoryear-comp` style and this is what I was expecting when using the `\textcite` command:

> CAO (no. 1234)

However, what is generated is this:

> Wilhelm et al. (CAO, no. 1234)

The plain `\cite` command, on the other hand, generates the citation as expected:

> CAO, no. 1234

The `@mvcollection` in this case is a 5-volume edition of medieval German charters and deeds which are ordered by number; I have each volume on file separately again. However, I was trying here to refer to an entry in the collection as a whole, since the enumeration of the individual records does not restart with each volume. What I don't understand is why `year` is replaced with `shorthand` instead of `editor` and `year` together when using `\textcite`.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    backend=biber,
    safeinputenc,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{CAO,
    editor = {Friedrich Wilhelm and Richard Newald and Helmut {de Boor} and Diether Haacke and Bettina Kirschstein},
    gender = {pp},
    title = {{Corpus der altdeutschen Originalurkunden bis zum Jahr 1300}},
    shorthand = {CAO},
    sortkey = {CAO0},
    volumes = {5},
    publisher = {Moritz Schauenburg and Erich Schmidt},
    location = {Lahr and Berlin},
    year = {1932--2004},
    pagination = {number},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[1234]{CAO}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\textcite` is a bit of a pain to modify. The following gives `shorthand` precedence over anything and makes sure the postnote is always wrapped in round brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{CAO,
  editor     = {Friedrich Wilhelm and Richard Newald and Helmut de Boor and Diether Haacke and Bettina Kirschstein},
  gender     = {pp},
  title      = {Corpus der altdeutschen Originalurkunden bis zum Jahr 1300},
  shorthand  = {CAO},
  sortkey    = {CAO0},
  volumes    = {5},
  publisher  = {Moritz Schauenburg and Erich Schmidt},
  location   = {Lahr and Berlin},
  date       = {1932/2004},
  pagination = {number},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx:postparens}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\ifnameundef{labelname}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
            {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
            {}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
            {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
            {}%
          \iffieldundef{labelyear}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
          \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
     \togglefalse{cbx:postparens}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \toggletrue{cbx:postparens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
     \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{togl {cbx:postparens} and not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}}
    {\togglefalse{cbx:postparens}%
     \printunit{\extpostnotedelim\bibopenparen\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}
    {\setunit{}%
     \printtext{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}}
    {\setunit{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}%
       \textcitedelim}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {}
        {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
         \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textcite[1234]{CAO}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This complains that `cite:labeldate+extradate` is undefined for regular instances of `\textcite`, at least on my system. I'm using Biber 2.4 and XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeXLive 2015 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Comment: @Jipí TeX live 2015 is a bit old now. The current version of `biblatex` is 3.10, you must be running 3.3 or thereabouts. A few macros have been renamed since then, a few new functions have been introduced. You can try to replace `cite:labeldate+extradate` by `cite:labelyear+extrayear`, but surely there will be more problems with your old system.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `\textcite` checks whether there is a `labelname` associated with the reference, and uses the shorthand if it is empty. For this particular entry the `editor` is being used as a `labelname`. If you don't want it to be used in such role you can use the option `useeditor=false`, which is also settable on a per entry basis, with `options = {useeditor=false},`. Notice this will change how the entry is formated in the bibliography, which actually makes sense, given the citation format. I believe this is semantically what you were looking for, but the result is not identical to what you expected (it looks like the plain `\cite`). But, perhaps `\parencite` would be also a possible "out-of-the-box" option (depending on your text flow, of course).

[image]

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    backend=biber,
    safeinputenc,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{CAO,
    editor = {Friedrich Wilhelm and Richard Newald and Helmut {de Boor} and Diether Haacke and Bettina Kirschstein},
    gender = {pp},
    title = {{Corpus der altdeutschen Originalurkunden bis zum Jahr 1300}},
    shorthand = {CAO},
    sortkey = {CAO0},
    volumes = {5},
    publisher = {Moritz Schauenburg and Erich Schmidt},
    location = {Lahr and Berlin},
    year = {1932--2004},
    pagination = {number},
    options = {useeditor=false},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[1234]{CAO}

\parencite[1234]{CAO}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```