# Omit date from shorthand citation in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, biblatex-chicago

When I am citing an entry with a shorthand with `biblatex-chicago`, the year gets printed along with the shorthand label. Is there a way to make Bibtex to just print the shorthand without the year, i.e. the way `authoryear` does?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    safeinputenc,
    natbib,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{paul2007,
    author      = {Hermann Paul},
    title       = {{Mittelhochdeutsche Grammatik}},
    shorthand   = {MhdG},
    edition     = {25. Aufl., neu bearbeitet von Thomas Klein, Hans-Jochim Solms und Klaus-Peter Wegera. Mit einer Syntax von Ingeborg Schröbler, neubearbeitet und erweitert von Heinz-Peter Prell},
    series      = {Sammlung kurzer Grammatiken germanischer Dialekte A. Hauptreihe},
    number      = {2},
    publisher   = {Niemeyer},
    location    = {Tübingen},
    year        = {2007},
    pagination  = {section},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{paul2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

This results in the following:

[image: Bibliography with wrongly formatted text citation]

What I want the in-text citation to look like is just 'MhdG' without the '2007'. If there are any pages indicated, those should stay in the normal way, of course.

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204020/164314) is what you are looking for. But since `natbib` is used, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203959/164314) would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of deleting a few lines from the relevant bibmacros. We need to modify two bibmacros, `textcite:authshort` for `\textcite`/`\citet` and `cite:shorthand` for all other cite commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    safeinputenc,
    natbib,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:authshort}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
      {\setunit{\multicitedelim}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
        {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}}}%
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}%
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
        \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
        \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
        \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
          {}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \ifboolexpr{%
            togl {cms@gencite}%
            and
            (
            test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
            or
            togl {cms@genallnames}%
            )
          }%
          {\thegen}%
          {}%
          \setunit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
          {}%
          \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}%
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \ifboolexpr{%
          togl {cms@gencite}%
          and
          (
          test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
          or
          togl {cms@genallnames}%
          )
        }%
        {\thegen}%
        {}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
        {}%
        \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printfield{shorthand}%
      \ifboolexpr{%
        togl {cms@gencite}%
        and
        (
        test {\iffinalcitedelim}%
        or
        togl {cms@genallnames}%
        )
      }%
      {\thegen}%
      {}%
      \setunit{%
        \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
        \cms@testspace\bibopenparen}%
      \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
      {}%
      \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
      {}%
      \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}}% Added ???
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
    \textcitedelim}}% Not \multicitedelim ???
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{paul2007,
    author      = {Hermann Paul},
    title       = {{Mittelhochdeutsche Grammatik}},
    shorthand   = {MhdG},
    edition     = {25. Aufl., neu bearbeitet von Thomas Klein, Hans-Jochim Solms und Klaus-Peter Wegera. Mit einer Syntax von Ingeborg Schröbler, neubearbeitet und erweitert von Heinz-Peter Prell},
    series      = {Sammlung kurzer Grammatiken germanischer Dialekte A. Hauptreihe},
    number      = {2},
    publisher   = {Niemeyer},
    location    = {Tübingen},
    year        = {2007},
    pagination  = {section},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{paul2007}

\citep{paul2007}

\citet{paul2007}

\citet[5]{paul2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MhdG (MhdG) MhdG MhdG, § 5]

---

The following code might help you to get the postnote in parentheses for `\citet`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
  {}%
  {\savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
    \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}{\postnotewrapper}{\addspace\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\bibopenparen}}%delim}%
    \printfield{postnote}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
  {\setunit{}%
    \printtext{%
      \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
      {}}}%
  {\setunit{%
      \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
      {}%
      \textcitedelim}}}% Not \multicitedelim ???
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, however it makes etoolbox throw an error: "Error: Invalid boolean expression." Maybe there's a bracket missing/too many somewhere? (Or maybe i should update Ubuntu 16.04 to get a more current TexLive?)

Comment: @Jipí The exact MWE worked for me on a fully updated MikTeX with `biblatex` 3.11, Biber 2.11 and `biblatex-chicago` 1.0rc5. The TeX live that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 is outdated by today's standard, so I can't guarantee that this solution will work with your ancient version. Unfortunately, `biblatex-chicago` is a very complex style and I can't obtain the old version that you are using easily. You don't need to update your Ubuntu, it would be enough to install the vanilla TeX live (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) if you are up for that.

Comment: @Jipí I see we had that conversation before in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416228/35864. `biblatex` 3.3 trails behind current development eight versions and almost two and a half years. With actively developed projects such as `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` there comes a point at which you can't really expect complicated lower-level and internal stuff like this to work smoothly any more.

Comment: I updated by manually installing TeXLive 2018, and now it works as it should. Is there a way to get MhdG (§ 5) from `\citet[5]{paul2007}` in addition to the above solution?

Comment: @Jipí I added an attempt. If that does not help or has bugs, I suggest you open a new question with an MWE and more details (test cases and expected output).

Comment: This seems to work, i.e. it compiles with the desired result. Thank you!